# How to get the value of observable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get the value of totalDeals then add a logic to check if its > 0 but I am receiving an error :

```
Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Subscription' and 'number'.ts(2365)
```

[image]

- **code**

  ```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.leaseId = this.transaction.leaseId;

    this.getAllDealsCount();
  }

  getAllDealsCount() {
    let totalDeals = zip(this.getCount('ForApproval'),this.getCount('Draft'))
    .subscribe(res => this.totalDeals = res[0].data + res[1].data)
  }

  private getCount(item: any) {
    let status = item;
    return this.dealService.getCount(
          this.accountId,
          this.transaction.id,
          status
    )
  }
  ```

Comment: Try using `forkJoin` instead of `zip`.

Comment: any example Sir ?

Comment: Just replace `zip` with `forkJoin` For more info [Refer here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/mastering-rxjs-operators-and-functions-that-can-bite-you-when-you-dont-expect-cb2047cf5d4c)

Comment: @deprecated — Use the version that takes an array of Observables instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
getAllDealsCount() {
    const observableResult = zip(
        this.getCount('ForApproval'), // observable 1
        this.getCount('Draft') // observable 2
    );

    // subscribe to the final observable 
    observableResult.subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      const forApprovalResponse = res[0]?.data;
      const draftResponse = res[1]?.data;
     
      this.totalDeals = forApprovalResponse  + draftResponse;
       
       if (forApprovalResponse > 0) {
          // ... logic goes here
       }

       if (draftResponse > 0) {
         // ...logic goes here
       }

       if (this.totalDeals > 0) {
          // do something with it
       }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir , how do we seperate the total of ForApproval only , and the total of ForApproval +Draft status ?

Comment: I wanted to get both , total of both and total for ForApproval Alone

Comment: is that possible in a single function @Andres2142 ?

Comment: @AgastyaKumar I don't understand what you want exactly, when you subscribe to `observableResult`, you have both answers, `res[0].data` (ForApproval) and `res[1].data` (Draft), and `totalDeals`. What else do you need?

Comment: How do we know that the result which ForApproval only between the 2 ? res[0]?.data  and res[1]?.data

Comment: Because, when you use `zip`, subscribes to each `observable` you put into it, it goes in order, this case, `forApproval` followed by `draft`

Comment: By the way you have idea with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122401/how-to-call-function-from-another-component-in-angular/69122507?noredirect=1#comment122168003_69122507